# Using PlasTex, How can I control the size of my images using \includegraphics

Tags: graphics

I am running plasTex 1.0.0 and I cannot properly control my image size.  Using the `\includegraphics[width=10in]{path_to_image}` command plasTex fails to resize the image at all, outputting the original size.  If I use `\scalebox` or `\resizebox` I can begin to size my images, but they have an arbitrary upper size limit.  I have checked my python packages for extra commands but I do not have any at my disposal.  I have also tried just putting the image in a `minipage`environment but that outputs the original size image.  Is there a way to size these images more effectively?

The Code:

```
\ifplastex
   \begin{figure}[h!]
     \scalebox{0.5} 
  {\includegraphics{1_gettingstarted/tutorial_images/1_interfaceLayout.png}}
     \caption{test}
  \label{fig:interfaceLayout}
  \end{figure}
  \else
\fi
```

Comment: I should note that I am using plasTex to convert to html.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  With  plasTeX 0.9.1 I have not this problem, in HTML format it add   `style="width:10in"` and the image is displayed accordingly.  It is not possible to say much more without more information (ideally a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your input and output).

Comment: But the final size in the browser is not necessarily 10in, if that is the question. I guess that the zoon and monitor settings also matter.

Comment: Beyond 8.1 inches of width the image is cut off to the right hand side.  So, the largest image width I can have is 8.1 inches.  Small than 8.1 inches works  but I want the image to be about 11 inches which results in a large portion of the image being cut off on the right hand side (1.9 inches worth).

Comment: Fran, Could you please provide me with your code?  I have given my code above.  Thanks

Comment: Fran, using my code the image HTML comes out to be:  <img src="images/img-0003.jpg" alt="\includegraphics[width=10in]{1_gettingstarted/tutorial_images/1_interfaceLayout.jpg}" style="width:1920px; height:941px">  Thus it has added the alt="width=10in" but has not changed the style tag

Answer (score 1):

As requested by the OP, an example that not reproduce the issue, with a image of width 10in and 1in without/with a float, both not cropped and showing the correct size with JPG images:

[image: JPG]

The page was generated with plasTeX 0.9.1 in this way:

```
plastex file.tex
```

**`file.tex`**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=10in]{example-image.jpg}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image.jpg}
\caption{xxx}
\label{xxx}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Compiled with pdflatex should produce this PDF:

[image: PDF-PNG]

**Note 1**: if the source is the PDF version of the image (example-image.pdf of the mwe package) plasTeX will produce an error.

**Note 2**: Work also with the PNG version, but note that the original example-image.png is a bit flattened with respect the PNG and PDF versions, so is not a fault of plasTeX:

[image: PDF-PDF]

Comment: Could you provide your graphicx.zpts file?

Comment: @nsahlin (1) there are more that one  graphicx.zpt
(2) In https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plastex/0.9.2-1.2 you all the files of my plasTeX version.